# How to safely delete django-allauth socialaccounts tables from my data

Tags: django-allauth

Please Note: I don't use any third party login accounts in my project, therefore I have no entries in my Database regarding socialaccount app.

I would like to remove following tables from my Database:
[image]

How to do that safely without breaking my currently working app. As I said this tables are empty and does not contain any data. If I just drop them and remove the django-allauth `socialaccounts` app from my installed apps, can I be sure that the django-allauth will continue to work without errors.

It also would be better to mention that in the docs that this `allauth.socialaccounts` app is not required if we don't want to use third party accounts to login.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove data from Models created by django-allauth (to remove relations with your Database project). You find this models in Django Admin.
2. Remove all django-allauth of your project. `INSTALLED_APPS`, additional `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, `SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS`, Template loads like `{% load socialaccount %}`, `{% providers_media_js %}`, etc.
3. **Drop/cascade** all django-allauth tables of your database.

Comment: I don't want to remove `django-allauth` by it self. I just want to remove the socialaccount part of it.